# Обработка исключений Java

Tags: java, исключения

Доброго времени суток.
Решал учебную задачу

```
public class Solution {
    public static StatelessBean BEAN = new StatelessBean();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileSystemException {
        try {
            processExceptions();
        } catch (FileSystemException f) {
              BEAN.log(f);
        }
     }

     public static void processExceptions() throws FileSystemException {
         try {
            BEAN.methodThrowExceptions();
         } catch (FileSystemException f) {
             BEAN.log(f);
             throw f;
         } catch (CharConversionException c) {
             BEAN.log(c);
         } catch (IOException i) {
             BEAN.log(i);
         }
     }

    public static class StatelessBean {
         public void log(Exception exception) {
             System.out.println(exception.getMessage() + ", " + exception.getClass().getSimpleName());
         }
         public void methodThrowExceptions() throws CharConversionException, FileSystemException, IOException {
             int i = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
             if (i == 0)
                throw new CharConversionException();
             if (i == 1)
                throw new FileSystemException("");
             if (i == 2)
                throw new IOException();
          }
    }
}
```

Задачу не приняли из-за того,что в сигнатуре метода `main()` не нужно указывать класс перекидываемого в него исключения `throws FileSystemException`. Объясните пожалуйста, почему так делать нельзя.

Comment: throws используется как обозначение возможного исключения. Причем, если исключение unchecked, то фактически вы просто обозначаете это для читающих информацию о методе (т.е. никто не обязывает вас это делать, но так иногда принято). Если же исключение типа checked, то вам остается или обработать его внутри метода, или "перебросить" наверх с помощью throws, чтобы обработать выше. Однако таким образом, если все время "перебрасывать" исключение выше вы дойдете до метода main(), которому "перебрасывать" уже некуда и приложение приостановит работу. В нормальных приложениях такое недопустимо.

Comment: Спасибо, вы многое разъяснили

Comment: Конкретно в данном случае `throws FileSystemException` у `main` не нужно, т.к. метод его не бросает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код не должен падать никогда. Он должен выдавать сообщение о том, что что-то пошло не так, может закрываться, но не должен говорить системе, что он сломался. Это дурной тон. Представьте, что вы создали приложение, в которое можно записать ФИО человека и его дату рождения. При парсинге даты вы обнаружили, что пользователь ввёл запятую вместо точки, и вы вместо того, чтобы выдать пользователю предупреждение / сообщение об ошибке - падаете полностью. Нехорошо получается

Comment: если я Вас правильно понял, то: trows мы указываем только в том случае, если мы собираемся перебрасывать его дальше?

Comment: Да. Насколько я помню, это указание на то, какие исключения могут вернуться из этого метода.